# LibGDX. Endless Runner creating a 'ceiling'

Tags: java, libgdx

I am pretty new to this entire thing but I have a couple months of messing around with different tutorials. 
I recently stumbled across this tutorial
http://williammora.com/a-running-game-with-libgdx-part-1/ 
and have been able to complete it with no errors.

At this point I am looking to test different set ups for the Endless Runner.
I like the idea of having unlimited jumping to create a Flappy Bird style control. I have run into some issues however.
Specifically, I am trying to create an invisible ceiling to keep the runner from going above a certain height.

If anyone would be willing to look through the tutorial and help me create this ceiling I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check your's bird Y coordinate against some min/max values. And if it's lower than min set it to min and if it's higher than max set it to max.

But if you don't want you bird slamming into invisible border you can do a nicer Y transition, like adding some negative acceleration if bird is close to max/min values and the closer it is add bigger acceleration. Something like acceleration = 1 / distance from min or max.... With some coefficients ..

So, after the code that moves your crazy bird, you can add something like:

```
if (bird.y < MINY) bird.y = MINY;
if (bird.y > MAXY) bird.y = MAXY;
```

Where MINY and MAXY are constants...you defined somewhere above..

Comment: If I went for the first suggestion, would I have to create a method under the runner class or the gamestage?  And if it wouldn't be too much trouble, do you have an example code for this check?

Sorry if I am being a bother, you have been very helpful with just this comment :)